# Unable to receive Push Notification messages when the MobileFirst app (Android) is stopped

Tags: notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I have implemented a Push Notification feature in my MobileFirst Android app.
However, I find that my app cannot receive any push notification messages if the app is stopped. Even my app run again, the missing message will not receive.

I have read other articles about the similar issue in stackoverflow or other websites. However, I cannot find the solution for my case.

Comment: Where is your coding effort?

Comment: 1) Add your AndroidManifest.xml **to the question**; 2) better explain the issue - are you saying that the message is **received and displayed** in the notification center but the app will not open when the notification is tapped, or something else? explain.

Comment: In addition to what Idan asked, also provide logcat from the device

Comment: @luen mo, where are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good if you could clarify what do you mean by "stopped".
Stopped as in swiped out from the applications view, or forced-stopped from the application settings.

Force-stopped applications (via Settings >> applications >> your-application >> kill app) will no longer receive notifications, be (Android) design.

This is because the intent service which handles received notifications has  also been killed due to this force-stopping.

This is unlike simply closing an application by swiping it out, which will not kill the intent service thus the app will continue to receive notifications even if not running (because its intent service is still running).